# How can I know which user I used to co a svn repository?

Tags: svn

How can I know which user I used to co an svn repository?

Is there an svn command for this?

**update:**

so, how can I ci as some users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN working copies aren't checked out *as* a certain user (though on some systems the files will be owned by a certain user, who created them).

SVN only records users on revisions, so it is only relevant to ask which user committed a certain revision.

Comment: If you do `svn help ci`, you will see the options. Use `--username` to specify user.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn ci --username YourUsername
```

The online help of svn is really useful, check it out! For example, `svn help ci`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running Svn via Apache, you cannot tell who checked out from the repo. If you are running via Apache, you can see who did what from Apache's access logs.